# A Callback to $.each()'s Callback?

Tags: jquery, loops, callback

**Update:** The code below does indeed work as expected, and accomplishes the code I wanted.  My confusion was in understanding what I had in my markup when writing the code below - after giving my markup a second look, I realized my code worked perfectly.

I've provided [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335752/a-callback-to-eachs-callback/1335952#1335952) for all who are interested in the more thorough explanation.

---

I'm trying to delay an action until after a $.each() cycle has completed, but cannot seem to get it working. More specifically, I'm cycling through a series of DIV's to determine the tallest, and then setting the height of all to that value, but I have to wait until I have that highest value before I can set the height of the others:

```
/* Fixing Module Heights */
$("div.module-box").each(function(){
  maxHeight = 0;
  $("div.module-body", this).each(function(){
    currentHeight = $(this).height();
    if (currentHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = currentHeight;
  });
  $("div.module-body", this).css("height", maxHeight);
});
```

It should turn this:

```
<div class="module-box">
  <div style="height:75px" class="module-body">Hello World</div>
  <div style="height:10px" class="module-body">Hello World</div>
</div>
<div class="module-box">
  <div style="height:50px" class="module-body">Hello World</div>
  <div style="height:13px" class="module-body">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Into this:

```
<div class="module-box">
  <div style="height:75px" class="module-body">Hello World</div>
  <div style="height:75px" class="module-body">Hello World</div>
</div>
<div class="module-box">
  <div style="height:50px" class="module-body">Hello World</div>
  <div style="height:50px" class="module-body">Hello World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: In what way does it fail? Nothing happens, or the wrong height is set? I'm asking since your example isn't complete: Your divs need to have class 'module-body' and be nested in a div with 'module-box'.

Comment: It simply reapplies the current height for its back to itself. Each stays their initial height.

Comment: Sorry, in my code they had the class - the example is updated now.

Comment: Try with my second example. I've not tested it but i think it works

Comment: Your code works for me.

Comment: @mck89 I need the height to be set only after every module-body has been tested against the maxHeight, not during. Thank you for giving it a shot though :)

Comment: @Gumbo - Seriously? Let me go and double-check my CSS/Markup then, maybe I'm missing something on my end.

Comment: I just created a test page with your code in it, and yes, it does indeed work here.

Comment: Ah, looks like my code does work. My brain, not so well. My example here didn't properly illustrate my local-code. I need to rewrite it slightly, but I've got it figured out - thanks guys.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no problem here. The code provided here works perfectly with the markup provided here. The issue was with my local-markup; it wasn't exactly the same as the markup provided here in an attempt to simplify the markup:

```
<div class="module-row">
  <div class="module-box">
    <div class="module-body">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="module-box">
    <div class="module-body">
      <p>Hello World</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note here in my example there is only one .module-body within each module-box. For this reason, the .each() was setting the module-body's height to whatever it was to begin with.

What I intened to do was test each module-body within every module-row. My altered code looks like this:

```
$("div.module-row").each(function(){
  maxHeight = 0;
  $("div.module-body", this).each(function(){
    currentHeight = $(this).height();
    if (currentHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = currentHeight;
  });
  $("div.module-body", this).css("height", maxHeight);
});
```

The only difference is the first selector. It used to be "div.module-box" and is now "div.module-row".

Thank you to everybody here who helped me discover my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
var maxHeight = 0, currentHeight=0;
$("div.module-box").each(function(){ 
    currentHeight = $(this).height();
    if (currentHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = currentHeight; 
});
$("div.module-body").css("height", maxHeight);
```

If you want that relative to their parents:

```
$("div.module-box").each(function(){ 
var maxHeight = 0, currentHeight=0;
    $(this).children("div").each(function(){
    currentHeight = $(this).height();
    if (currentHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = currentHeight;
    }).css("height", maxHeight); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this, I understand what's wrong here, apologies for not getting it immediately

```
$("div.module-body").each(function(){
  $("div.module-body", this).css("height", maxHeight);
});
```

After the first each block.  That way for each box of div's you will run two each loops.  One gets the max height and the other sets it.

Comment: Please look at my example again, I am setting the height after the $.each().

Comment: My bad, did my edit address that?

Comment: `this` in that context is necessary to not confuse various div.module-box's.

Comment: Correct, however you iterate over every one of them anyway, in this isntance jQuery would modify all of them at the same time which is essentially what is accomplished by the each() loop.  Another alternative is to have another each() loop after the original one that does nothing but set all of the heights.

Answer (score 1):

I added the index on each loop and check when last element is reached to set the maxHeight:

```
/* Fixing Module Heights */

$("div.module-box").each(function(){

  maxHeight = 0;

  moduleBodies = $("div.module-body", this);

  moduleBodies.each(function(i){

    currentHeight = $(this).height();

    if (currentHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = currentHeight;
    if (i == moduleBodies.length -1) $("div.module-body", this).css("height", maxHeight);
  });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is the issue but you should use **var** when declaring your variables.

```
/* Fixing Module Heights */
$("div.module-box").each(function(){
    var maxHeight = 0;
    $("div.module-body", this).each(function(){
        var currentHeight = $(this).height();
        if (currentHeight > maxHeight) maxHeight = currentHeight;
    });
    $("div.module-body", this).css("height", maxHeight);
});
```